# <object> is not JSON serializable django

Tags: python, json, django

I have a list of all product with all specifications .
So now i want to send JsonResponse with that list with pagination of 10 product at a time.
when i try to send all product

```
all_pro = Products.objects.all()
return HttpResponse(all_pro )
```

it gives me a error  is not JSON serializable.

my product model

```
class Products(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True, blank=True)
    posting_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1,null=True, blank=True)
    extra_text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

So how can i send JsonResponse to front end.
Thanks in advance.
**I am not using drf**

I want to send Json Object

Comment: You can not simply hand in the `QuerySet` to `HttpResponse()`. You have to serialize the objects into a simple Python structure like a dictionary.

Comment: methinks that code is not producing that error. Can you post your actual code. Also let us know if you are using DRF or not

Comment: i am not using DRF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the above mentioned methods are good. But I prefer

```
all_pro = Products.objects.all().values('product_name', 'category', 'price')
return JsonResponse(list(all_pro))
```

JsonResponse can be imported from

`from django.http import JsonResponse`

This also makes sure your query fetches only required fields from database.

Sample response:

```
[{'product_name':'Data1', 'category':'cat1', 'price':10},{'product_name':'Data2', 'category':'cat2', 'price':5}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a [`serializer`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) to serialize the model object to 
JSON and then return the response. For example, if you are using [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/), you may create a file *serialzers.py* as:

```
from models import Products
from rest_framework import serializers


class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Products
```

Then in your *views.py*, you have to call it like:

```
from serializers import ProductsSerializer

all_pro = Products.objects.all()
data = ProductsSerializer(all_pro).data  # serialize the data
return HttpResponse(data)
```

Comment: This assumes they are using DRF, but there is no evidence of that in the question.

Comment: I am not using DRF

Comment: this is not solving my problem.

Comment: @vikrantVerma: This solution assumes that you are using DRF. Since you are not DRF, go with the other answer mentioned by sideeffect

Answer (score 3):

You can use django serializer from core package,

```
from django.core import serializers
all_pro = Products.objects.all()
data = serializers.serialize('json', all_pro, fields=('product_name','category', ))
return HttpResponse(data)
```

But i recommend using [rest_framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/) or [tastypie](https://github.com/django-tastypie) for better solutions.